# Power BI Cumulative Sum for Previous Months

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following dataset:

[image]

I have created the following measure:

```
NumStdReqCreatedByMonth = COUNTX(StdReq;StdReq[Created].[Month])
```

using measue I have the following table: 
[image]

I want the following:

[image]

sum of tickets created in previous months.

Do you know how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what issues did you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
Backlog =
CALCULATE(
    [NumStdReqCreatedByMonth],
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED( 'Calendar' ),
        'Calendar'[Date] < MIN( StdReq[Created] )
    )
)
```

Assuming there is a Calendar dimension table which has one-to-many relationship with StdReq table, this calculates the number of tickets created before the earliest date in selected period. If selected period is November 2019, then it counts the tickets created by October 31, 2019.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to calculate the backlog of one month:

```
    BackLogNovember = CALCULATE(
[NumStdReqCreatedByMonth];
FILTER(
    ALLSELECTED( StdReq );
    StdReq[Created] < Date(2019;11;01) 
)
```

)

is it possible to iterate this function for each month and generate a table?